# Use XML code in string.format

Tags: windows-phone-7, formatting

I was wondering if it is possible to use string.Format to make certain text's say bold, and other italic? Something like

```
string.Format( "<Bold>{0}</Bold>", some text in bold );
```

is this possible, or should I add a Bold every time I want to add something in Bold?

Comment: `string.Format` can be used to generate a new *string* replacing the `{..}` tokens with the corresponding values. Is that what you *want*? And, if so, what could be the repercussions if other markup can come from the values?

Comment: Well, yeah kinda, only I would like to know if it is possible to add textformatting to a certain string, using xml or whatever, so that when I add it to a richtextbox, it will automatically be bold, insteadf of having to use the Bold class every time I want to use this. ( Reason is, I need to create a CV, and would like to use this simple way, instead of 3 or 4 lines of code every time I want to add some sort of textformatting ).

Comment: because, the string.format only listens to very specific commands, so if I were to try every command I could think of, if it even is supported, would take me a long, long time

Answer (score 0):

What this will do is replace `{0}` with `some text in bold`. so your output of `string.Format` will be `<Bold> some text in bold</Bold>`

Does this output produce bold and italics in your VS? I suppose it will not. Unless you are passing this into something else that can display it in the specified format of bold or italics

Comment: True, I tried this already, but gave it as a reference of how I would like to create such a string in the string.Format method. So my question is: is there such a way to make clear to the string that it should support XML. So that, when I am adding it to a richtextbox, which does support textformatting: Oh, this should be bold

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to evaluate whether this is a good technique without seeing the context within which you are using it. But, it seems simple enough to me. You could wrap this in a static method:

```
public static string Embolden(string text)
{
   return string.Format( "<Bold>{0}</Bold>",text);
}
```

However, if you are doing a lot of XML manipulation, I would suggest that you generate your XML using one of the XML APIs such as Linq-to-XML / `XDocument`. Code like the above is OK in small doses!

Comment: OK. Because what I'm doing now, is create a CV. This shows some user-information, such as Surname: name, where Surname should be bold, and the name should be plane text. I do this for about 10 specifiactions to a user, and can't use XAML, because not all fields are filled in sometimes. So it states then: Facebook: 
Which is ugly. But these API's for XML formatting are native to WP7?